# Speeding up 4 million mongodb updates

Tags: python, performance, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

We have a defaultdict with ~4 million entries like:

```
my_dict = {'page_abc': 1234545, 'page_asdf': 54231}
```

We have a mongoDB collection with ~10 million entries, where each document is:

```
{'page':'page_abc', 'volume': 321, '_id':whatever}
```

This is indexed by `_id` (mongodb default) and by `page` (which I set).

I need to update the collection only with the pages that exist. My code was initially:

```
for page, volume in my_dict.iteritems():
    entry = c.db.coll.find_one({'page':page})
    if entry:
        c.db.coll.update({'_id':entry['_id']}, 
                         {'$set':{'volume':entry['volume']+volume}})
```

But this turned out to take about 3 hours. I sped it up by crawling the collection only once:

```
for entry in c.db.coll.find():
    if entry['page'] in my_dict:
        c.db.coll.update({'_id':entry['_id']}, 
                         {'$set':{'volume'+log_file_date:my_dict[entry['page']]}})
```

This takes about 58 minutes. This is still really slow considering I need to do this every day. 
Can this be sped up??

My thoughts at the moment:

- Maybe remove the default _id index - or even remove that all together? The dual indices could be slowing things down
- Maybe delete keys from the dictionary as they are iterated past? I think dictionaries are pretty fast with O(1) lookups even for such a big size though

Edit: I timed my updates and precisely I can do 3227 per second. Can that be improved upon? Or have I reached a hardware limit (7200rpm seagate st2000dm001 cc43)

Comment: Your bottom code still does 4 million `find_one` operations that you don't need to do.

Comment: Ah yes sorry just a typo - question still stands though

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the $inc operator. This way you don't need to do the find and you can do the update immediately. Here is the code:

```
for page, volume in my_dict.iteritems():
    c.db.coll.update({'page':page},{'$inc':{'volume':volume}})
```

Since the upsert argument is not set to True, the document will be updated if and only if it exists.

Edit:
Even when you want to add a new attribute, you can do it in one call. I don't understand why you need to do the find. Here is the code:

```
for page, volume in my_dict.iteritems():
    c.db.coll.update({'page':page},{'$set': {'volume'+log_file_date:my_dict['page']}})
```

Comment: Ah sorry I think I simplified the problem too much. Actually its setting a new attribute per date (see edit above) in each document. Perhaps I could have these volume counts as a list in each document and simply append a [date, volume] to each list using push?

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your edit. But I added an edit to my answer that probably addresses your concern. My point is that you don't need to do the find. You can perform the update directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The reason I do the find is also because later I want to insert the pages that don't exist. I will try upserting - perhaps that will speed things up a bit

Comment: So I tried your upsert idea. Actually upserts are about twice as slow as my solution :(

Answer (score 0):

How many entries do you have in your MongoDB collection ?
If it is an order of magnitude less, you could just get the result of c.db.coll.distinct('page') into the memory, and then filter in memory, rather querying one-by-one to mongoDB.
If the collection contains too many entries, you might be able to chunk your pages in to blocks (let's say - 1000 pages in a block), and then run distinct on results of find({'page':{'$in' : block_of_pages}}).